# How do i check if url string contains a word in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3

I'm trying to forward the web view to a local file if URL doesn't contain words I want I tried many things **contains** and **rangeofstrings** didn't work for me.

```
  if let url = "http://facebook.com/url/url"{

        if url.contains("facebook.com") || url.contains("nocontent") || url.contains("nointernet") || url.contains("paypal.com"){
            //Doing something here
            return true
        }else{

            let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "nocontent", ofType: "html")
            let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: just covert url into string & use code as var string = "hello Swift"

if string.range(of:"Swift") != nil{ 
    println("exists")
}

// alternative: not case sensitive
if string.lowercased().range(of:"swift") != nil {
    println("exists")
}

Comment: @Gagan_iOS i tried doesn't work please read the question properly

Comment: try this one ..some time 'contains' does not work. Covert your url into string & check for range as mentioned in first comment.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS it's a string please read the question

Comment: `return URL(string: "http://facebook.com/url/url")?.absoluteString.contains("facebook.com") == true` or using the host property `return URL(string: "http://facebook.com/url/url")?.host?.contains("facebook.com") == true`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://facebook.com/url/url") {

    if url.absoluteString.range(of: "facebook.com") != nil {

        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Tip: you don't need the enclosing parenthesis.

Comment: @BoilingLime "http://facebook.com/url/url" will be replaced with NSURL dont worry

Comment: @O-mkar Ok, use `URL` instead `NSURL`. But `URL` nor `NSURL` implement `range(of: String)`. You'll have to unwrap the `absoluteString` as follow : `let urlString = URL(string: "http://facebook.com/url/url")?.absoluteString`

Comment: Even "simpler" if there's only one condition: just `return url.absoluteString.range(of: "facebook.com") != nil` or `return url.absoluteString.range(of: "facebook.com") == nil` depending on the logic you need. ;)

Comment: Why don't you use `contains`?

Comment: `return URL(string: "http://facebook.com/url/url")?.absoluteString.contains("facebook.com") == true`

Answer (score 5):

Works for me as well:

```
if url.absoluteString.contains("facebook.com") {
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
guard url.path.contains("facebook.com")  else { return nil }
 //do what you want
```